# Better way to create an object into array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object/array statements and when it is not an array i want to make it to an array, what i try is as follows:

```
var statements = policy_blob['Statement'];
if(!$.isArray(statements)) {
  var statements_ = statements;
  statements = []
  statements[0] = statements_;
}
```

It is working fine for me but i am looking for the better alternative. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Array `[]` or object `{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single line using ternary syntax.

```
var statements = $.isArray(policy_blob['Statement']) ? policy_blob['Statement'] : [policy_blob['Statement']];
```

---

Or do it after caching in a variable.

```
var statements = policy_blob['Statement'];
statements = $.isArray(statements) ? statements : [statements];

// or using Short-circuit evaluation property of `||`(logical or)
var statements = policy_blob['Statement'];
$.isArray(statements) || statements = [statements];
```

Refer : [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: True, and the duplicated property lookup won't make any difference basically ever.

Comment: Thanks @Pranav for saving my time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all at once:

```
statements = [statements];
```

e.g.:

```
var statements = policy_blob['Statement'];
if(!$.isArray(statements)) {
    statements = [statements];
}
```

The right-hand side is evaluated before being assigned to the left-hand side, there's no problem with having the same variable on both sides of it.

Live example:

```js
var policy_blob = {
  Statement: 42
};
var statements = policy_blob['Statement'];
if(!$.isArray(statements)) {
    statements = [statements];
}
console.log(statements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```